# How to create TCP client in NodeJS using async/await?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, promise, async-await

I have written the following `tcp client` in nodejs.

```
const net = require('net');

const HOST = 'linux345';
const PORT = 2345;
let ErrCode = 1;

const client = new net.Socket();

client.connect(PORT, HOST, function() {
    ErrCode = 0;
});

client.on('data', function(data) {    
    console.log('Client received: ' + data);
     if (data.toString().endsWith('exit')) {
       client.destroy();
    }
});

client.on('close', function() {
});

client.on('error', function(err) {
    ErrCode = err.code;
    console.log(ErrCode);
});

console.log(ErrCode);
```

Please suggest how can I write same logic using async/await

I have looked into the following post but it is not helpful.
[node 7.6 async await issues with returning data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42440537/node-7-6-async-await-issues-with-returning-data)

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42440537/node-7-6-async-await-issues-with-returning-data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an amazing package that wraps the native **Node** socket in a promise. Allowing you to utilize `async/await` syntax on all socket methods.

The package can be found on [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-socket).

**Example**

```
import net from "net"
import PromiseSocket from "promise-socket"

const socket = new net.Socket()

const promiseSocket = new PromiseSocket(socket)

await connect(80, "localhost")
// or
await connect({port: 80, host: "localhost"})
```